# Embedded. Sharing ISR pool with tasks and allowing de-allocation

Tags: c++, embedded, freertos

I would like some guidance to an issue I'm facing. I'm working on my own embedded project and I've developed my own event bus to allow tasks to subscribe and publish events. I'm writing my software in c++, where my base class is of type Event (tasks queues expect a Event pointer). All application associated events and ISR events derive from this Event class.

From an application layer, all is working well from a design perspective. Every application Event has its own memory pool (template class) with appropriate locking and the task receiving the Event calls the delete operator, which I've overloaded inside the respective event and I perform deallocation. Note, within my memory allocator, I'm not using any heap either, just a mutex and marking the appropriate event as free within my memory pool.

Now, as I cannot use my memory pool within my ISR due to using a mutex, I still want my ISR to construct an event from a predefined pool (e.g. button event), post the event onto my event bus, and have the receiving task to use the ISR event and mark that item has free, once it has been used. All I'm passing around are pointers, via my event bus.

Ideally, when the receiving task receives an ISR event, the task performs a delete (which is overloaded) and marks that event as free (just set a flag). Because I'm passing pointers around (via my event bus), any modification will be reflected back inside the ISR pool.

Is it fare to say my solution of simply marking an ISR pool entry as free without locking is common when dealing passing data between ISR routines to my application layer? Not too sure the best approach of managing is issue

Thanks

Comment: This is all quite vague and broad. But generally: interrupts are low-level functions close to hardware that should be integrated inside the relevant driver. Events are application tier high-level concepts. Now if you decide to mix up the two somehow, you'll get an unholy mess. Perhaps it would be feasible if you have the ISR inside the driver do its job, then somehow have the driver signal to higher layers that something has occurred, by setting a flag or executing a callback etc.

Comment: But as always, carefully describe what problem your abstraction layers solves. If it creates problems instead of solving them, then you may have to rethink the whole design.

Answer (score 0):

Passing data from ISR's to application layers is a common source of problems/headaches. You don't provide information about your hardware platform, I presume you are working with a limited resources CPU, but you tag your question a freeRTOS so I'll assume this is the RTOS of your choice.

You could create your memory pool in some different way, like using a queue of free buffers instead of something protected by a mutex. You have [xQueueReceiveFromISR()](https://www.freertos.org/a00120.html) for trying to take a free buffer while inside of your ISR. Inconvenient with this method is all buffers in a queue must be of equal sizes.

If your communications needs are unidirectional, like having the ISR sending the data always to same task, then your could also evaluate using [Message Buffers](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-message-buffer-API.html). This has the flexibility that you can [send data](https://www.freertos.org/xMessageBufferSend.html) blocks of different sizes.